# Got Null Value From the api in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am fetching JSON values from the API...but it showing the values as null... I checked it in the postman it's working there and I have the response...I have listed my sample code below please mention my mistakes. I'm new to this development

```
- (IBAction)PaymentButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self PayuMoneyAdminValues];
}


-(void)PayuMoneyAdminValues{
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@admindatas",restSiteURLServices];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSString *userUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",restAuth];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setURL:url];
        //Convert the String to Data
    NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSData *data1 =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        //Apply the data to the body
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:data1];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(data!=nil){
            NSError *parseError = nil;
            NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
            if (parseError) {
                NSLog(@"Admin data: %@",responseDictionary);
            }
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    }
```

Comment: are you added the transportSecurity in your .plist

Comment: Please take time to format your code correctly.

Comment: At least handle (print) the `dataTask` error

Comment: Already added it @Anbu.karthik

Comment: If you have an error in the `NSJSONSerialization`, you print `responseDictionary`? No, print `parseError`. Please print the correct object, and print `data`.